# How to send messages in grpc bidirectional rpc without buffering from grpc node client

Tags: node.js, grpc

[RouteChat example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.3.2/examples/node/static_codegen/route_guide) which is a bi-directional rpc, seems to be buffering messages on [write](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.3.2/examples/node/static_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_client.js#L225). Is there a way to force writes to the outgoing stream immediately without buffering?

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing here? Is the writable stream buffer filling up? Are you seeing the buffer get backed up before the network link is saturated? Are you seeing too much latency between writing a message and seeing it on the wire? Or is it something else? Is this a problem you are observing with that example, or with your own code?

Comment: I am seeing a delay between writing a message and seeing it on the server. Specifically, all the messages written in the for loop [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.3.2/examples/node/static_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_client.js#L215) are sent to the server when [call.end()](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.3.2/examples/node/static_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_client.js#L227) is called as opposed to being written immidiately on [call.write(notemsg)](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.3.2/examples/node/static_codegen/route_guide/route_guide_client.js#L225)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this buffering behavior is because writes are actually completed asynchronously, so the server code needs to regularly allow other asynchronous operations to happen between writes to ensure that they are sent as soon as they are computed. You can take advantage of the optional callback argument to `write` to send each message immediately after the last one is sent. The code in that example can instead be written using [`async.each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each):

```
async.each(notes, function(note, next) {
  console.log('Sending message "' + note.message + '" at ' +
      note.location.latitude + ', ' + note.location.longitude);
  var noteMsg = new messages.RouteNote();
  noteMsg.setMessage(note.message);
  var location = new messages.Point();
  location.setLatitude(note.location.latitude);
  location.setLongitude(note.location.longitude);
  noteMsg.setLocation(location);
  // Note the use of the next callback here
  call.write(noteMsg, next);
}, function() {
  // End the stream after all messages have been sent
  call.end();
});
```